# I want to use a time out in my mini program

Tags: c#, timer, timeout

I have a mini program that read an excel file. Well, sometimes, my program doesn't work well and keep remaining with do nothing. So, I want to catch this, and if my program delay more than 5 minutes, I want to stop this process.

So, How I can do this ?

I try this, but doesn't work

```
 aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
 aTimer.Enabled = true;
 aTimer.Start();  
 read_file(f, sDir, pathOut, pathLogOut);
```

Comment: Should it check for tasks to do, or what do you want specifically?

Comment: What do you do when the timer elapses?

Comment: When the time elapses, I want to read a excel file and change some cells, and after, save the excel file. My fuction read_file make this.